# Symfony2 render twig template

Tags: php, symfony

It may be a lame question but I been struggling for few hours now to get this working.

I just stared playing around with Symfony Framework and hit the wall whilst trying to render a Twig template went through the docs but still unable to get the path to the template right.

Error:

`Unable to find template "BlogCoreBundle::index.html.twig" (looked into: /Users/Tomazi/Dev/udemySymfony/app/Resources/views, /Users/Tomazi/Dev/udemySymfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form).`

DefaultController:

```
<?php

namespace Blog\CoreBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('BlogCoreBundle::index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

my template is located at:

```
path_to_bundel/Resources/views/index.html.twig
```

What is it that I am doing wrong..?

Comment: It doesn't seem to look for the template in the BlogCoreBundle folder. Have you added BlogCoreBundle to AppKernel?

Comment: Your path is src/Blog/CoreBundle/Resources/views/index.html.twig ?

Comment: can you make a default directory and put your view in ?